# The service cannot be found for the endpoint reference while User Store Configuration Deployer initialization

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

from time to time our api throws 500 Http codes. I tried to track down the problem and found this kind of errors in the wso2carbon.log:

```
TID: [0] [AM] [2017-03-05 20:06:11,687]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.TenantAxisConfigurator} -  Creating tenant AxisConfiguration for tenant: aTenant[2] {org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.TenantAxisConfigurator}
TID: [0] [AM] [2017-03-05 20:06:11,726]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.store.configuration.deployer.UserStoreConfigurationDeployer} -  User Store Configuration Deployer initiated. {org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.store.configuration.deployer.UserStoreConfigurationDeployer}
TID: [0] [AM] [2017-03-05 20:06:11,730] ERROR {org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine} -  The service cannot be found for the endpoint reference (EPR) local://axis2services/some/api/path {org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine}
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The service cannot be found for the endpoint reference (EPR) local://axis2services/some/api/path
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.DispatchPhase.checkPostConditions(DispatchPhase.java:78)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:329)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:261)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:167)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.MultitenantMessageReceiver.processRESTRequest(MultitenantMessageReceiver.java:594)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.MultitenantMessageReceiver.doNhttpREST(MultitenantMessageReceiver.java:534)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.MultitenantMessageReceiver.doREST(MultitenantMessageReceiver.java:353)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.MultitenantMessageReceiver.processRequest(MultitenantMessageReceiver.java:212)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.MultitenantMessageReceiver.receive(MultitenantMessageReceiver.java:79)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:344)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:168)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
TID: [0] [AM] [2017-03-05 20:06:11,803]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.DeploymentInterceptor} -  Deploying Axis2 service: wso2carbon-sts {aTenant[2]} {org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.DeploymentInterceptor}
TID: [0] [AM] [2017-03-05 20:06:11,856]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine} -  Deploying Web service: org.wso2.carbon.sts -  {org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine}
TID: [0] [AM] [2017-03-05 20:06:11,860]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.DeploymentInterceptor} -  Deploying Axis2 service: wso2carbon-sts {aTenant[2]} {org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.DeploymentInterceptor}
TID: [0] [AM] [2017-03-05 20:06:11,926]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.multitenancy.TenantServiceBusInitializer} -  Intializing the ESB Configuration for the tenant domain : aTenant {org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.multitenancy.TenantServiceBusInitializer}
```

After `Deploying Axis2 service:...` everything runs fine.
So it seems that api calls can not be processed while the UserStoreConfigurationDeployer is running. But this happens between 10 and 20 times a day, causing several errors.
The [javadoc](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-identity-framework/blob/master/components/user-store/org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.store.configuration.deployer/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/user/store/configuration/deployer/UserStoreConfigurationDeployer.java) says:

```
/**
 * This is to deploy a new User Store Management Configuration file dropped or created at repository/deployment/server/userstores
 * or repository/tenant/<>tenantId</>/userstores. Whenever a new file with .xml extension is added/deleted or a modification is done to
 * an existing file, deployer will automatically update the existing realm configuration org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.store.configuration
 * according to the new file.
 */
```

But these files are never touched.
I'm not an expert for wso2, so can someone point me where to search? Can the UserStoreConfigurationDeployer be configured to run only at start or only once a day (at 2:00 am or something)?

We are currently using wso2am-1.8.0, the upgrade to 2.something is planned.